# cross origin request via xmlhttprequest

Tags: cross-domain

I'm new to xmlhttprequest, and I need a little help with cross origin requests.

I make a xmlhttprequest from web service, everything is going nice and smooth from my local host.

but when I'm running from the server I get cross-origin exception (that's because the origin (site) and the web service are not located at the same location)...

I've tried to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to '*' threw req.setRequestHeader function without success.

P.s I'm writing in javascript.

I'll be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is:

We can't locate our client files in one server and make a httprequest to another,
for security reasons the browser blocks the request...

so the options are:

1. To locate both client & server files in on the same server.
2. There couple ways to manipulate the server which include changing scripts in the server files (really not recomended for beginners... )

Enjoy